# pymongo "Projection" to exclude all fields and only get selected fields?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Using mongodb projection we can define which filed to include and which one to exclude.

like this :

```
data = db.Users.find_one({'username': user },{"_id":0,"password":0,"email":1})
```

This Query will exclude the `_id` and `password` fields and only include `email` ,

**But is there a way to exclude all the fields present in a document and only fetch `email` and `phone`**,

In smaller documents I can set the project value to 0 for the items I dont need but for larger documents , **is there a way to automatically exclude all other fields/items and only get the ones that are required ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific command/syntax you have provided actually is *not* valid:

```
> db.Users.findOne({'username': 'user' },{"_id":0,"password":0,"email":1})
MongoServerError: Cannot do inclusion on field email in exclusion projection
```

You can see the same failure in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LyvXn_R5V64).

By default though, projection is going to do exactly what you want. From the [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#return-the-specified-fields-and-the-_id-field-only):

> **Return the Specified Fields and the _id Field Only**
> A projection can explicitly include several fields by setting the `<field>` to `1` in the projection document.

So if you replace the (invalid) `"password":0` component of your projection with `"phone":1` to make the command as follows:

```
data = db.Users.find_one({'username': user },{"_id":0,"phone":1, "email":1})
```

It will behave like you want. Demonstration in [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wsXUFwfbeE8).